# Pymongo arayfilters not worked

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have in MongoDB collection named `locations` field `ip_addresses`. This field looks like this:

```
[['178.150.147.148'], ['198.16.78.43']]
```

I want to add a new ip_address at specific position in `ip_addresses`. For example, "192.162.78.101" in the first list(where '178.150.147.148' is).
Desired output:

```
[['178.150.147.148', '192.162.78.101'], ['198.16.78.43']]
```

My query in `pymongo`:

```
find_index = 0
new_date = "12/29/2019"
ip = "192.162.78.101"    
db.locations.find_one_and_update({"date": new_date},
                                 {"$push": {"ip_addresses.$[element]": ip}},
                                 {"multi": False, "arrayFilters": [{"element": {"$eq": find_index}}]},
                                  # Try using each and position but didn't succeed
                                  # "$each": ['ip'],
                                  # "$position": find_index}}},
                                  upsert=True,
                                  return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

But I got error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: No array filter found for identifier 'element' in path 'ip_addresses.$[element]'
```

Tried searching through pymongo and mongodb docs - if `arrayFilters` implement in pymongo, because I couldn't found any example using it. Without `arrayFilters` might be the chance to got what I want here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pymongo, array filters are specified as an argument to the function, not within an object. This is probably what you are looking for:

```
find_index = 0
new_date = "12/29/2019"
ip = "192.162.78.101"    
db.locations.find_one_and_update({"date": new_date},
                                 {"$push": {"ip_addresses.$[element]": ip}},
                                  upsert=True, multi=False,
                                  array_filters=[{ "element": { "$eq": find_index }}]
                                  return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

However, this works only if `find_index` contains an ip address that is in the array you want to append into; i.e, it would work if `find_index='178.150.147.148'`. In other words, the above statement is saying: "add '192.162.78.101' to the sub-array that already contains '178.150.147.148'".

If what you want to specify is the index of the sub-array, just use the positional dot notation, like this:

```
db.locations.find_one_and_update({"date": new_date},
                                 {"$push": {"ip_addresses.0": ip}},
                                  upsert=True, multi=False,
                                  return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

Comment: It's almost what I want! But, `find_index` - this is number, which specify to which array should we add our `ip`. For example, in my question, I want to add to the first sublist `ip` '192.162.78.101' - that's why `find_index=0`. So, instead of `{"element": {"$eq": find_index}}` maybe I can use something like `{"element": {"$position": find_index}}`?

Comment: Or how to replace `0` with `find_index` in this example:`{"$push": {"ip_addresses.0": ip}}`. Something like `"$push": {"ip_addresses.find_index": ip}`?

Comment: tried today `'$addToSet': {'ip_addresses': { '$each': [ip_address],'$position': find_index}}}`, and got: `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Found unexpected fields after $each in $addToSet: { $each: [ "178.150.147.148" ], $position: 0 }`

Comment: It's strange but `{'$addToSet': {'ip_addresses.$[element]': ip_address}},
                                             array_filters=[{"element": find_index}],
                                             upsert=True, multi=False,
                                             return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)` don't add an item in `ip_addresses`

Comment: Read the second part of the response, it explains how to update the subarray based on the index, using `{ "$push": { "ip_addresses.0": ip }}`. Just substitute `0` with the value of `find_index`, something like `{ "$push": { f"ip_addresses.${find_index}": ip }}`. What you are trying to do with `$position` will not work because you have nested arrays, and in that syntax `$position` will refer to the position in the sub-array, not the parent array.

Comment: Tried last commit got `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Cannot create field '$0' in element {ip_addresses: [ [ "192.162.78.101" ] ]}
`

Comment: Finally, I can make it works by two queries: one use for get how concrete nested array looks like and second: using array filters and search this array using results from the first query. By position array filters not worked

Comment: `one = db.locations.find_one_and_update({"date": new_date},
                                                   {'$push': {'ip_addresses.$[element]': ip_address}},
                                                   array_filters=[{"element": {'$eq': current_ip}}],
                                                   upsert=True,
                                                   return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)`

Comment: Thanks for your help!) I can deal with this using your example